# Play youtube video inline

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can i play a youtube video inline?

I've been searching for this for quite some time, since i need to create buttons underneath, for getting notification on click of fast forward and rewind button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [LBYouTubeView](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView) or [XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController)

Comment: It's generally best to avoid link only answers in case the links stop working eventually.